# The use of "are kept occupied" is grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice

Tourists are kept occupied by many sights in Singapore.
Is the use of "are kept occupied" grammatically correct? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Simply put, yes, it is grammatically correct. To "keep someone occupied" means to give them something to do for a period of time. (http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/keep-someone-occupied)

Answer (score 3):

It is grammatical, but it sounds odd in this context, because (as I read it), the use of the quite purposeful phrase "to keep [somebody doing something]" implies that somebody is purposefully keeping them occupied, and the usual reading is that this is to stop them doing something else.

Comment: Well, perhaps the local covernement or the tourist board don't want them to notice the seedier sides ;-)

Comment: Indeed, something like that is the implication I read into the words.